# Regularity in EEG data

Tags: eeg

[image: EEG data]

I've just started looking into EEG data using a Muse s and mind monitor. I've noted this very regular 4 Hertz (approximately) pattern and wonder if this is real or an artifact. Is it just a very regular delta wave? My understanding is that this is the raw real time levels from different sensors. The time between dashed lines is one second.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is rather a electro-physiological question than a pure signal processing question.  Nevertheless, from my experience it does not look like eeg/brain signals at all.

Answer (score 1):

TP9 and AF7 are definitely not brain waves. AF8 is more realistic, but still too clean; I suspect both it and TP10 were heavily filtered. Possibly TP9 and AF7 had negligible activity and were dominated by equipment noise, where a single frequency prevails (e.g. 60Hz), so its bandpass filtering would show such regularity.

I'd dig around in the app for a way to display the data in raw form.

Comment: I will thanks!  .